# How to update state when props from Link change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-state, ethers.js

I'm fetching data from a smart contract in component1 like this (this is a menu with Links:

```
const [contract, setContract] = useState()

  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])
  const getData = async () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
    await provider.send('eth_requestAccounts', [])
    const campaignContract = new ethers.Contract(
      process.env.REACT_APP_CAMPAIGNS_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
      CampaignsAbi,
      provider,
    )
    
    setContract(campaignContract)
    const numberOfProjects = await contract.numberOfCampaigns()

    const campaigns = []
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfProjects; i++) {
      campaigns.push(await contract.campaigns(i))
    }
 
    setProjects([...campaigns])
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [contract])

  return (
    <div className="App-top-bar">
      <div className="App-top-bar-menu">
      
        <Link className="link" to="/projects">
          <MenuButton title={'Donate'} />
        </Link>
        <Link
          className="link"
          to={{
            pathname: '/projects/my-projects',
          }}
          state={projects}>
        
          <MenuButton title={'My Projects'} />
        </Link>
  
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

The path '/projects/my-projects' leads to a 'MyProjects.js'.

```
//index.js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MoralisProvider serverUrl={serverURL} appId={applicationID}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
            <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />}>
              <Route path="/projects/my-projects" element={<MyProjects />} />
         </Route>
          </Route>
          <Route
            path="*"
            element={
              <div>
                404 :(
              </div>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </MoralisProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

This is what it looks like:

```
const MyProjects = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ProjectList />
    </div>
  )
}
const ProjectList = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const { state: projects } = useLocation()

  return (
    <div className="donate-body">
      {projects && projects.length !== 0 ? (
        projects.map((campaign) => <Project projectDetails={campaign} />)
      ) : (
        <h1>No Projects</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want my 'ProjectList' to update when the data in the contract changes and 'projects' changes. Any help? Feels like I'm making a React mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `useEffect` hook to enqueue a state update to "synchronize" the passed route state with the local component state.

Example:

```
const ProjectList = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const [projects, setProjects] = useState(location.state);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProjects(location.state);
  }, [location.state]);

  return (
    <div className="donate-body">
      {projects.map((campaign) => (
        <Project projectDetails={campaign} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Keep in mind though that it's generally considered anti-pattern in React to store passed state/props/etc into local component state. It's common to consume the values directly.

Example:

```
const ProjectList = () => {
  const { state: projects } = useLocation();

  return (
    <div className="donate-body">
      {projects?.map((campaign) => (
        <Project projectDetails={campaign} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Update

If you want a single source of truth then I suggest using a React Context to store the `projects` state.

Example:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

export const ProjectsContext = createContext({
  projects: [],
  setProjects: () => {},
});

export const useProjects = () => useContext(ProjectsContext);

const ProjectsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState(location.state);

  return (
    <ProjectsContext.Provider value={{ projects, setProjects }}>
      {children}
    </ProjectsContext>
  );
};

export default ProjectsProvider;
```

Provide the context.

```
import ProjectsProvider from '../path/to/ProjectsProvider';

...

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ProjectsProvider>
      <MoralisProvider serverUrl={serverURL} appId={applicationID}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
              <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
              <Route path="/projects/my-projects" element={<MyProjects />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="*" element={<div>404 :(</div>} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </MoralisProvider>
    </ProjectsProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Projects

```
import { useProjects } from '../path/to/ProjectsProvider';

...


const { setProjects } = useProjects();

useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    await provider.send('eth_requestAccounts', [])
    const campaignContract = new ethers.Contract(
      process.env.REACT_APP_CAMPAIGNS_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
      CampaignsAbi,
      provider,
    );

    setContract(campaignContract);
    const numberOfProjects = await contract.numberOfCampaigns();

    const campaignsPromises = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfProjects; i++) {
      campaigns.push(contract.campaigns(i));
    }

    const campaigns = await Promise.all(campaignsPromises);

    setProjects(campaigns);
  };

  getData();
}, [contract]);

return (
  <div className="App-top-bar">
    <div className="App-top-bar-menu">
      <Link className="link" to="/projects">
        <MenuButton title='Donate' />
      </Link>
      <Link className="link" to='/projects/my-projects'>
        <MenuButton title='My Projects' />
      </Link>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

MyProjects

```
import { useProjects } from '../path/to/ProjectsProvider';

...

const MyProjects = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ProjectList />
    </div>
  );
};

const ProjectList = () => {
  const { projects } = useProjects();
  return (
    <div className="donate-body">
      {projects.length ? (
        projects.map((campaign) => <Project projectDetails={campaign} />)
      ) : (
        <h1>No Projects</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This works, but the props are passed only on navigation (when I click the 'MenuButton') and that's when the list updates. How can I do this without that?

Comment: @enchante That's how route state works, it's not passed until the link is clicked and the navigation action is invoked. Can you clarify what you are trying to if using route state isn't what you want?

Comment: I want the items in the list in component2 to update if they update in component1

Comment: @enchante The first example in my answer does exactly that, updates the local `projects` state from the passed route state. This is also anti-pattern though. Don't duplicate your state because you run into stale state and synchronization issues. It's preferable to have one single source of truth for your state values that all components use. Is that what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @enchante Ok, then the `projects` state should be pushed up to a common ancestor component, like the component rendering the routes, and can then be passed down as props. If this is what you are after then can you update your question to include the component rendering the routes and these two components?